# Represent Relative Difference in Linear Programm

Tags: linear-programming

I am using a linear program to model some capacity problem. I have some limit x and I can calculate with my LP about which amount y my solution exceeds this capacity. However, for the final result I need not the absolute difference but the relative difference e.g. like y/x. I am really thinking hard how to solve this, but i cannot find a good solution which confuses me since I have the feeling when I have one I nearly already have the other too.
Right now I would assume I have to represent 1/x e.g. via a piecewise function, and then reprenset the product y * 1/x in other ways, which is very complicated.
Any help?
Thanks a lot!
Oliver

Comment: Sometimes we can multiply the whole equation by `x`. E.g. `a <= y/x <= b` can be linearized by `ax <= y <= bx`.

Comment: Could you please post your lp?